# PHP Iframe | Refresh every X time and flip through array of pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

This is the javascript code for refreshing the content of the IFRAME every 60 seconds.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var timer;
        function refreshIframe(){
        if(timer)
        clearInterval(timer)
        timer = setTimeout(refreshIframe,60000)
        var iframe = document.getElementById('dashboard'); 
        iframe.src='XXXX.php';
        }

        refreshIframe();
    </script>
```

The actual Iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe id="dashboard" width="100%" height="1250" src="XXXX.php" frameborder="0" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have managed to refresh the page (content only), but currently I do not know where to start with multiple pages.

As an example I have **page1.php**, **page2.php** and **page3.php** and I would like that on load up of the page will be page1.php and after each refresh 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3 .... continuously

Any suggestions, samples, where to move to make this happens will be appreciated.

Thank you

**P.S. - v1**

I can assume, that that should assign a link to a variable, then put this variable inside the array and scroll through them??? - This is an idea, I'm not 100% sure how to do it.

Comment: Chuck a counter in and each time `refreshIframe()` is called increment the counter; use that to determine which page to use for the `iframe.src`

Comment: @CD001 what thinking about the counter, sorry for limited knowledge, but okay it will count to 1 then 2 then 3 ? what is the nice way to come back to 1 again? As it should be continuously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take pages in an array `pages` and a counter `count` , which increment with every time src for iframe changes. And code will be like:

```
var timer,
        pages = ["abc.php", "cde.php", "xyz.php"],
        count = pages.length,
        i = 1;
function refreshIframe() {
    if (timer)
        clearInterval(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(refreshIframe, 60000)
    var iframe = document.getElementById('dashboard');
    iframe.src = pages[(i - 1) % count];
    i++;
}

refreshIframe();
```